# maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare fails with "Error writing POM: (Access is denied)"

Tags: tfs, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I try to run mvn release:prepare (of course, after release:clean), and I get an error:

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) ...: Error writing POM: D:\\pom.xml (Access is denied)**

**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:...\pom.xml (Access is denied)**

The problem: The file IS IN THE specified location, but it is write-protected (because it is under SCM). All poms must be checked-in, otherwise I get an error in earlier stage (check-poms phase). So pom must be checked-in, i.e. write-protected, hence I get "access denied" exception, and it does not make any sense!

After downoading the maven sources scm-plugin and release-plugin), I tried to find something but unfortunately could not find a reason for this exception. Maybe I am missing something, so I post it here, maybe someone can shed some light.

I've added logs in several points in the code (in DefaultReleaseManager, so I can see the phases), re-built and I see that it fails on phase called '**rewrite-poms-for-release**', which is the phase where maven tries to change my poms into release, and check them in again. But the thing is that these poms are under source-control, so they are read only. So the plugin cannot write to these poms, so it returns the error 'access denied'.

Tried to see if there is something in the relevant class, `class RewritePomsForReleasePhase extends AbstractRewritePomsPhase`, but found nothing. Tried to run it with -X, so i got the relevant exception (see below).

I work with maven-release-plugin:2.5, maven-scm-plugin:1.9, the provider is TFS (but I do not see how it is relevant for my error, since it does not fail in the 'provider' or in the scm-plugin.)

---

**UPDATE**:

Just tried to reproduce with maven-release-plugin:2.1, which I know works for sure (with maven-scm:1.4). I get the same error. So I guess something in my configuration is incorrect... Maybe there are experts here that can help? Maybe it is related to the maven-scm-plugin?

```
[INFO] Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf status -workspace:ohad -recursive -format:detailed $/NNG/PLS/dev/PLS/PLR"
[DEBUG] line -There are no pending changes.
[INFO] err -
[DEBUG] Iterating
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= check-dependency-snapshots
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= create-backup-poms
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= map-release-versions
What is the release version for "referencedata"? (com.ccih:referencedata) ***: : 6.6.0-RELEASE
What is the release version for "referencedata.resolvertool"? ***: : 6.6.0-RELEASE
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= input-variables
[INFO] scmUrl - https://***:$/***
[INFO] Scheme - https
What is SCM release tag or label for "referencedata"? ***: :
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= map-development-versions
What is the new development version for "referencedata"? ***: :
What is the new development version for "referencedata.resolvertool"? ***: :
[INFO] *** DefaultReleaseManager(): phase name= rewrite-poms-for-release
[INFO] Transforming 'referencedata'...
[INFO] scmUrl - https://***:$/***R
[DEBUG] Using mirror nng (http://192.168.244.13:8081/artifactory/nng) for plt-release (http://192.168.244.13:8081/artifactory/plt-release-local).
[DEBUG] Using mirror nng (http://192.168.244.13:8081/artifactory/nng) for plt-snapshot (http://192.168.244.13:8081/artifactory/plt-snapshot-local).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.ccih:ccih-platform-dependencies:pom:6.5.0600.0000: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] No SCM translator found - skipping rewrite
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] referencedata ..................................... FAILURE [2:16.083s]
[INFO] referencedata.resolvertool ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:16.696s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 22 15:55:20 IDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project referencedata: Error writing POM: D:\<correct path>\pom.xml (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project referencedata:
 Error writing POM: D:\Dev\projects\NNG\PLS\dev\PLS\PLR\pom.xml (Access is denied)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error writing POM: D:\Dev\projects\NNG\PLS\dev\PLS\PLR\pom.xml (Access is denied)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Error writing POM: D:\Dev\projects\NNG\PLS\dev\PLS\PLR\pom.xml (Access is denied)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:685)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:632)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformProject(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:241)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transform(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.execute(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:277)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Dev\projects\NNG\PLS\dev\PLS\PLR\pom.xml (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter.<init>(XmlStreamWriter.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.WriterFactory.newXmlWriter(WriterFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:666)
        ... 31 more
```

---

Comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the maven-scm-provider-tfs. Meaning, the TFS support for maven-scm-plugin is not full.

I've opened a [JIRA item [SCM-752]](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-752) for this, and a fix was suggested. It will be released in the next release (1.10) of maven-scm-plugin.